# Printing out range of a pattern with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, regular-expression

Im trying to print out a section of a txt file using awk. Basically I want to print out the paragraph in the a txt file that begins with certain words all up to a blank line.Here's what I have so far:

```
awk '$1 == "What exactly is Free", $1 == "^$" {print $1}' br.txt
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you paste the text example. What is happening when you run the `awk` you provided?

Comment: Nothing happens when i run it. Heres the text file http://pastebin.com/wHUp5bff

Comment: You sure you want `awk`? `sed '/What exactly is Free/,/^$/!d'`

Comment: @mikeserv: `awk` also has a comma operator: `awk '/What exactly is Free/,/^$/'`

Comment: @zackse - even if true, `sed` is still faster. Why would you use the slower tool to do the exact same thing?

Comment: @mikeserv: I agree with choosing the faster tool, but the question author asked to use `awk`.

Comment: @zackse - and that is why I asked if the asker was sure and suggested otherwise in a comment.

Comment: @mikeserv: no issues with your answer, I was just pointing out that `awk` offers the same construct. If the question author is concerned with speed, then `sed` is the way to go as you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n"} /What exactly is Free/' br.txt
```

This should print the entire paragraphs where the text is found (`RS="\n\n"`).